# Could not able to Delete the log file in Log4j in Java

Tags: apache

```
@BeforeTest
public void testLogin() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // Log4j.logMessage("Deleted the Existing LogFile");
    // DeleteFile.deleteFile();
    Log4j.logMessage("Login the application");
    // Login.loginsession();
    Log4j.logMessage("Logged in the application");
}

@Test
public void testChangePassword() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Log4j.logMessage("Change Password Test Case Started");
    // ChangePassword.changepwd();
}

@AfterTest
public void testLogout() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    // Logout.logoutsession();
    Log4j.logMessage("Logged out the application");
}
```

If I use the below,

param name="Append" value="true"

All the runs are logged in the log file.. If I set false, only Last message is logged..I wanted to log entire run (if i start new run, older logs should be deleted and only current run should display)

I am trying to Delete the file @BeforeSuite but delete is NOT working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method by add maxBackupIndex.
Here is the reference:
http://www.cnblogs.com/sky7034/archive/2012/01/16/2323268.html